# Packet Size modification over Sockets

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, network-programming, network-protocols

I am doing socket programming in QT and I have to design a protocol to transfer data over TCP/IP.

Now my protocol design is simple. It sends commands in a fashion that the first byte of the data written to the socket for every write will be the command. So whenever I write into the socket using socket->write("CDATA") the first byte, "C" in this case will mean a command for the server to do something.

I just want to know one thing, that whether the write will be broken down into multiple reads on the server ? I know there will be a buffer size on the server for the read. But can the socket->write() on the client be recieved in multiple reads on the server when the write is within the buffer limits of the server ?

To clear this question I will given an example Lets say the buffer read size of the socket on the server is 4096 bytes. The client writes socket->write("CDATA") to the server. Now is there any possibility that server will receive this in more than one read? Because I have a while loop on the server :

```
while{
 char str[] = socket->read();
 // What is the coomand in the first byte 
 if(str[0] == "C"){
  // Do something
 }
}
```

If the data sent by the client is received in more than one read (even though the client sent it in one write) my protocol design will fail.

Comment: Due to your weird use of capitalized words, I'm now trying to decode any pleas for help that your message may contain.  DON'T WORRY MAN ITS GONNA BE ALRIGHT

Answer (score 1):

> Now is there any possibility that server will receive this in more than one read?

Yes, TCP/IP can fragment messages any way it likes.  TCP is a stateful stream protocol: you are guaranteed that bytes you put in on one end will come out the other end in the same order.  IP is connectionless and datagram based.  Due to the nature of carrying TCP over IP, circumstances can arise in which data packets are split, merged, or otherwise processed in transit.

You should find a way to sanitize your program to the intricacies of network communication.  You can:

- Use a datagram protocol like UDP (you lose the guarantee of getting data in the order they are sent, and dropped packets becomes a possibility as well.  Today's networks are fairly robust; this is not usually a problem).

  ```
  [DATAGRAM (size specified in datagram header)]
  ```
- Always read blocks of a fixed size from the network

  ```
  [DATA - block of data of some fixed size]
  ```
- Include the size of the incoming data as a header attached to the front

  ```
  [LENGTH - 4 byte integer][DATA - block of data of size LENGTH]
  ```
- Use some sort of delimiter to indicate end-of-data and continue reading until you get it

  ```
  [DATA - indeterminately sized data][DELIMITER - end-of-data control sequence]
  ```

Chances are you can use library methods to perform this behavior for you requiring very little code on your part.

Comment: For instance: HTTP is newline delimited. SFTP is a datagram protocol.  FTP, I think, uses a header. Minecraft uses a header.  SSH, telnet, and other character shell protocols are basically delimited by every character.

Comment: "Include the size of the incoming data as a header attached to the front" That is exactly the question here sir. Lets say if I include a header of 4 bytes and a data of 4096 bytes, but the data is received as 2 bytes and 4098 bytes on the server. What should I do in this case ? OR will the data be received in 4 bytes and 4096 bytes of continuity.

Comment: Chances are you can use `read` to read data of a specified size.  I can't find any documentation that supports your use of `socket->read()`, all of the docs i've found take arguments.  If you have a wrapper class or something, post it.  Anyway, you can use `QByteArray QTcpSocket::read (qint64 maxlen)` to read some specified number of bytes from the stream.

Comment: Just because @Wug mentioned, FTP looks very close to HTTP, if you consider only the header and delimiters.

Comment: I just want to know if the writes done at the client end are received as the same way when you read it at the server (considering each write is within the buffer limit of the server)

Comment: No, they are not the same.  Your code seems to rely on the magic property that the receiving code knows exactly how large the incoming data is, which it does not.

Comment: So with each write on the client, there should be a header sent with it describing the length of the packet ? How does FTP work ?